# PHP unique visitor count without database

Tags: php

I have done up a simple PHP visitor count, but it is without a database and I am just storing it in a text file. However, the view count increases even if the user refreshes the page. I am thinking of coming up with a unique counter where the counter will only increment after the previous session is destroyed and the user goes on to the site again. However, I am not sure as to how to implement the session.

PHP Code:

```
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r"); 
                 if(!$handle){ 
                  echo "Could not open the file" ;
                   } 
                  else { 
                    $counter = ( int ) fread ($handle,20) ;
                    fclose ($handle) ;
                    $counter++ ; 
                    echo" <p> Visitor Count: ". $counter . " </p> " ; 
                    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ) ; 
                    fwrite($handle,$counter) ; 
                    fclose ($handle) ; 
                    }
```

Comment: I would imagine that if you want to register only unique visits that you will have to check against the users. If the IP is the same for the person refreshing the page, then do not count. Otherwise, count it.

Comment: install google analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start a session, so that we can keep track if this is the first time the user is visiting this site **in this session**.

Next we check if the session "counter" is set, if it is, we do nothing, otherwise we update the hit counter with +1 and set the session "counter".

This should do the job for you.

```
<?php
           session_start(); // Should always be on top
           if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) { // It's the first visit in this session
             $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r"); 
             if(!$handle){ 
              echo "Could not open the file" ;
               } 
              else { 
                $counter = ( int ) fread ($handle,20) ;
                fclose ($handle) ;
                $counter++ ; 
                echo" <p> Visitor Count: ". $counter . " </p> " ; 
                $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ) ; 
                fwrite($handle,$counter) ; 
                fclose ($handle) ;
                $_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
                }

           } else { // It's not the first time, do not update the counter but show the total hits stored in session
             $counter = $_SESSION['counter'];
             echo" <p> Visitor Count: ". $counter . " </p> " ;
           }
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying 'Undefined index: counter' after the second else

Comment: @nurul98 It's because the first if statement was checking if sess_user was set. Oops. My bad. I've updated the code again and it should now work!

Comment: I wonder if the session method might be TOO exclusive. I tried this on my own visitor counter and was surprised to see the count increment once, but then NOT increment again even after closing and re-opening the browser, or even trying a different browser. The only way i got it to increment and prove it worked was to open the page on my Iphone browser, a totally different machine. I'd have thought that if, for example, the browser was shut down and then someone else used the computer, opened the browser, and visited the site, it would increment. Guess I'll need to check my PHP.INI to see why.