# How can I add a visitor counter in my WebPage?

Tags: javascript, php, counter

I was trying to add a simple PHP or, if possible, a JS code to my website.
I didn't find any solution and I don't know much about both PHP and JS... is there anyone who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't do it without a server that will store the variable of visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
 If you want to have a simple example this code can help you based on this [link](https://html-online.com/articles/simple-php-mysql-visitor-counter/)

```php
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "dtbsuser";
    $password = "dtbs#passw01";
    $dbname = "dtbsname";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "UPDATE Counter SET visits = visits+1 WHERE id = 1";
    $conn->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT visits FROM Counter WHERE id = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $visits = $row["visits"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "no results";
    }
    
    $conn->close();
?>

<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Visit counter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Visits: <?php print $visits; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

And if you want to read more about how count the unique view you can look at this [link](https://www.edopedia.com/blog/how-to-create-website-visitor-counter-php-mysql/)

And at the end if you want to have unique views without database you can look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534078/php-unique-visitor-count-without-database)

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

I read this interesting article from https://hibbard.eu/how-to-make-a-simple-visitor-counter-using-php/ .

It just reads if the file counter.txt exists.
If not, a "0" is written.
It this file exists, read the number, adds 1 and writes the updated counter.

May be it helps.

The same example explains you how to use images instead of text.